# Unable to run project based on jboss-fuse

Tags: jbossfuse

I am newbie to [RedHat-fuse](https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/overview/) and also to `apache-Camel`. 

I was following the [build-your first app tutorial](https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/get-started/#fndtn-eapruntime) of RedHat for developimg my first project in RedHat developer studio.

But when I hit url after deploying project to server http://localhost:8080/eap-camel?name=Kermit , I got a 404.

I am not sure about what's wrong. I have simply followed their instructions in installation and setups. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Difficult to answer. Try `log:display` command in JBoss Fuse command line, is there any ERROR? Try `list` command, your bundle should be at the end of the list in ACTIVE state.

Comment: I installed fuse uisng EAP (not Karaf). I am even unable to get console. Their documentation is quite over my head

Comment: This link explains how to get into command line or using the web interface to administer EAP: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/paged/getting-started-guide/chapter-2-administering-jboss-eap
Make sure your application is installed and running

Comment: Thanks. But I have successfully run EAP server, but was following https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-fuse/6.3/paged/developing-and-deploying-applications/chapter-3-getting-started-with-developing for developing demo project. But I am unable to find locations like `/bin/.fuse` and hence unable to startup a container